# onItemClicklistener not working in custom list view

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have set `onItemClicklistener` on my custom list view but `onItemClicklistener` not working
I also tried the set `focusable="false"` and `focusableInTouchMode="false"` on controls of custom list view. I have also seen related questions but not help.

Kindly help please

```
 public class SwipingActivity extends Activity {
 public OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);

        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int padding = 0;
            private int initialx = 0;
            private int currentx = 0;
            private  ViewHolder viewHolder;
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    padding = 0;
                    initialx = (int) event.getX();
                    currentx = (int) event.getX();
                    viewHolder = ((ViewHolder) v.getTag());
                }
                if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    currentx = (int) event.getX();
                    padding = currentx - initialx;
                }

                if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                {
                    padding = 0;
                    initialx = 0;
                    currentx = 0;
                }

                if(viewHolder != null)
                {
                    if(padding == 0)
                    {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000 );
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), viewHolder.text.getText().toString(), 5);
                    }
                    if(padding > 75)
                    {
                        viewHolder.setRunning(true,viewHolder);
                    }
                    if(padding < -75)
                    {
                        viewHolder.setRunning(false,viewHolder);
                    }
                    v.setBackgroundColor(viewHolder.getColor());  
                    v.setPadding(padding, 0,0, 0);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        ModelArrayAdapter adapter = new ModelArrayAdapter(this, getData(),gestureListener);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setFocusable(true);
        lv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView txt = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt.getText().toString(), 5);

            }
        });
    }
```

@sam I have added the code. Kindly check it....

Comment: Please post the relevant code so that we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess but did you call ListView.setOnItemClickListener()? I believe that you want to keep `focusable` and `focusableIntouchMode` set to `true`.

**Addition**

You must call show() to display a Toast, change this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt.getText().toString(), 5);
```

to this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt.getText().toString(), 5).show();
```

Here too:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), viewHolder.text.getText().toString(), 5).show();
```

**Another Addition**

Your OnTouchListener is consuming the event before it reaches your OnItemClickListener, simply have onTouch() return `false`.

Comment: I have tried focusable and focusableIntouchMode to true and also calling  ListView.setOnItemClickListener() but not working. Please help :(

Comment: I cannot see your code from here, you must post (at a minimum) the Java code concerning your ListView and OnItemClickListener.

Comment: No errors coming and nothing seems to be done at onItemClick.

Comment: now onItemClick is running but onTouch is not. So How do I solve it. :(

Comment: Ok, what does your onTouch() do? For instance if `padding == 0` could you return `false` and allow the onItemClick() to be called, but if `padding != 0` return `true`?

Comment: I used onTouch() for swipe gesture implementation and if I return false it will not works.

Comment: But, what does your onTouch() **do**?

Comment: Kindly explain it from code, What exactly you want to deliver.

Comment: 'onTouch()' is touch listener that I am attaching in each view in the list,use swiping to interact with the list. Swipe right to enable the item and swipe left to disable the item.

Comment: Great and what about "no swipe" (`padding == 0`)? If you return `false` here, you will call onItemClick() and can execute whatever code you want (including changing the background color).

Comment: ok. So after swapping, will it possible for me to access the controls of custom list view at onItemClick listener. As after swapping another button appears and on that I want to perform some operation so how could I?

Comment: In your onItemClick() `AdapterView<?> arg0` is a reference to your ListView, try accessing it like this: `ListView myListView = (ListView) arg0;` As for your question about preforming operations after a swap, you should ask whole new question for this be sure to include the relevant code and any logcat errors to help us with the context of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing on ItemClickListener within getView method of the custom adapter.
Now run the application .it will work fine